# Input range slider value should point to the output of the cgi script value on page load

Tags: javascript, html, bash, cgi

I have a `cgi script` which runs `bash script` inside it and gets a value as output. Now I want that value(output of `cgi`) to be assigned to the input range slider's value in `HTML` when the page loads initially. how do I achieve this?

```html
Minimum Length<br><input type="range" id="Minlen_range" name="MinlenRange" min="0" max="100" value="8" oninput="this.form.MinlenInput.value=this.value" />
<input type="number" id="Minlen_text" name="MinlenInput" min="0" max="100" value="8" oninput="this.form.MinlenRange.value=this.value" />
```

Below is the CGI script(testing.cgi)

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 echo "Content-type: text/html" 
 echo "" 
 echo "<html><head><title>Bash as CGI" echo "</title></head><body>"

 echo "<h3>Minimum Password Lenght</h3>" echo "<pre>
 $(/usr/local/bin/Propertyhandler getConfiguration minlen) </pre>"
```

Now, In the html page the default value is set to 8 but there I want that value property should point to output value of the cgi script.

Comment: Please show some fragments of the existing code at least to clarify.

Comment: Updated the post, please help